# Is Smart Contracts variable is updated?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

Lets assume im having `mapping(address => string) names` its likes storing user names with their address..`function get() return string{ return names[msg.sender]}`

and for retrieving the name

```
function setName(string memory name) return (string){
names[msg.sender] = name
return names[msg.sender]
}
```

in remix ide i can clearly get and setname with multiple accounts it works perfect... But when it comes to hardhat network locally i deployed but im getting empty string in get function and in set function it returns the string correctly.. After if i try to return the name by the same address im getting same empty string..

Im having a doubt. Am i using it wrong... Because im using that names variable as a database... Whoever set their name and retrieve it later right? But is this possible thats my question.. is that state is kept stored on blockchain or not? Any help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, states variables are stored in blockchain and are mutable/accessible through the types/methods you defined. So, what you're trying to achieve (Variables as a database) is right, and what happens on your hardhat is probably due to a local miss-configuration.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, Is there any solution for this like the correct config?

Comment: I'm not really into hardhat environment. My guess on your -miss-configuration- was due to your working remix-ide tries . I use Truffle+Ganache as my local environment.